# Ansible Tower can we pass hostname as variable to job template

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower

For Ansible Tower can we pass hostname as variable to job template , so that when the Job template is Run we can pass the host details dynamically during runtime and playbook would run on this host. Basiacally this variable should then update the inventory file

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes and no.  You can have a variable for the `hosts` in a play, and then set that variable in Tower.  So your playbook would look like this:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ my_host_variable }}"
  tasks:
    .
    .
    .
```

And pass `my_host_variable` in with the template.